# How to distinguish multiple directives in the same $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I actually call directive functions from controllers like this :

```
function myControllerFunction = function () {
    $scope.highlight();
}
```

`highlight()`, being a function in a directive.

What if I had two different directives, each one having it's own `highlight()` function ?

Is there a way to get the actual directive **object**, instead of accessing the directive function directly through the $scope ?

I would prefer to be explicit about the directive I want to use, like this :

```
function myControllerFunction = function () {
    $scope.myDirective.highlight();
}
```

Is that possible ?

If you are curious about why I want a controller talking to a directive, here is an example :

My controller receives an authentication pin from the user and submits it to a service. The service returns true if the pin is valid, otherwise false.

In my controller function, I check for the boolean return value. If it is true, I call a directive function, called highlight, which simply highlights a div in green if it is true, otherwise, I call it to highlight it in red.

Here is my controller function :

```
$scope.keypadEnter = function () {
    userService.isCodeValid($scope.code).then(function (result)
    {
        if (JSON.parse(result.data)) {
            $scope.highlight("lime").then(function () {
                $scope.code = "";
                $location.path('/clockin');
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.highlight("red").then(function () {
                $scope.resetDisplay();
                $scope.code = "";
            });
        }
    });
};
```

And here is my directive's highlight function :

```
...
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.highlight = function (color) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500);

        $element.find("span").css('color', '#000')
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                $element.find("span").css('opacity', 1).css('color', '#fff')
            });

        $timeout(deferred.resolve, 500);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
...
```

Based on your suggestions, I've changed my directive code to watch for the `$scope.color` variable, like this :

```
angular.module('clockin').directive('grDisplay', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            $attrs.observe('color', function (color) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500);

                $element.find("span").css('color', '#000')
                    .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                        $element.find("span").css('opacity', 1).css('color', '#fff')
                    });

                $timeout(deferred.resolve, 500);

                return deferred.promise;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And here's my view code :

```
<div data-gr-display ng-attr-color="{{ color }}" class="display"><span>{{code}}</span></div>
```

But I get this error :

```
TypeError: object doesn't support this property or method « observe »
   at link (http://localhost:18000/App/clockin/keypad/display-directive.js:6:13)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:18000/Scripts/angular.js:6692:13)
...
```

Comment: Rather than calling explicitly the function from the controller, wouldn't it be less confusing defining the scope object explicitly in the link function of each directive? i.e. $scope.highlightA = etc ? and then calling $scope.highlightA or B?

Comment: That is a good idea. Thanks ! The only thing is, since I've read Adlen's answer below, I'm not sure if I am doing things right (calling a directive from a controller method). Is there a better way to make that work ?

Comment: This is usually the job of a service, injecting it in your controller and using it's methods or data objects but if this works for you, I guess it's ok (it's not a problem until it is :P )

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a possible implementation, have a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange that your controller has to call method from directive. Could you provide more information of why you are doing this?

It seems that you want to allow your controller and directives talk together. For that here is a couple of options.

You may use events listeners like described in the `Creating a Directive that Adds Event Listeners` section of the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) if it is based on browser events

You could use [angular events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to broadcast events.

Finally you may want to adapt a parameter on your directive template saying that it is highlight.

**Edit based on the question edit:**

If you only need CSS change you may use the `ng-class` attribute on your directive like this:

```
<my-directive ng-class="{{ status }}"></my-directive>
```

Using an attribut you may do the following:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $attrs.$observe('color', function(color)){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500);

        $element.find("span").css('color', '#000')
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                $element.find("span").css('opacity', 1).css('color', '#fff')
            });

        $timeout(deferred.resolve, 500);

        return deferred.promise;
}
```

And in your view:

```
<my-directive ng-attr-color="{{ color }}"></my-directive>
```

Or if you want a notification system you may refer to [Angular UI Bootstrap alert](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/alert)
(but I still can't see why you need several directives for your problem)

Comment: I have edited my question to explain why I am doing this. Thanks.

Comment: You're right. I don't need more than one directive for my problem. I was just confused about controller --> directive communication, in case I would end up having multiple directives to handle in the same scope.

To answer your last comment, I'm not sure if it's only CSS change : I use the jquery-ui's highlight method. Is that feasible with ng-class ?

Comment: Not sure about using only CSS for jquery ui but I provided you with an attribute based example

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know about ng-attr. Where does ng-attr-color comes from ? Is that a custom name you gave to the attribute ? Actually, it's the background-color that I am highlighting. I also make the foreground color fade out.

Comment: It is just a way to avoid browser refusing some attributes. See angular doc here (`ngAttr attribute bindings` section) https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the changes you've suggested.

Comment: Sorry it is `$observe` and not `observe`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for your time. I understand a little bit more about the directives vocation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way you communicate with a directive is via attributes, you don't usually define methods in your controller scope at directive level.

I believe the right approach in your case would be with an attribute in your directive that binds to a scope property and your directive watches that property so when it changes it runs a particular function.

A possible implementation could be:

Controller:

```
$scope.onHightlight = function() {
   if ($scope.highlightColor === 'lime') {
       scope.code = "";
       $location.path('/clockin');
   } else {
       $scope.resetDisplay();
       $scope.code = "";
   }
});
$scope.keypadEnter = function () {
    userService.isCodeValid($scope.code).then(function (result) {
        if (JSON.parse(result.data)) {
            $scope.highlightColor = "lime";
        }
        else {
            $scope.highlightColor = "red";
        }
    });
};
```

Directive:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var onHightlight = $scope.$eval($attrs['onHightlight']);

    $scope.$watch($attrs['hightlight'], function(color) {

        $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500);

        $element.find("span").css('color', '#000')
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                $element.find("span").css('opacity', 1).css('color', '#fff')
            });

        $timeout(onHightlight, 500);
    }
 ....
}
```

HTML:

```
<your-directive highlight="highlightColor" onHighlight="onHightlight"></your-directive>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example based on the code I provided for my directive ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time on this. Having a directive watching the scope is the way to go.